# Linear Regression Model: Why is my test score higher than my training score?

Tags: python, machine-learning, regression, linear-regression

I'm running a LinearRegression() model using sklearn.  The dataset contains features for vehicles, such as engine size, cylinders, mpg, fuel type, and CO2 emissions.  The target variable is CO2 emissions.  I'm splitting the data 70/30.  When I calculate the scores for the training and test sets, the training set scores at 0.992 and the test set scores at 0.993. (The high accuracy for both seems to be due to the utilization of dummy variables for fuel type.  I re-ran the model without the dummy variables and the accuracy dropped a lot to 0.867 for train and 0.870 for test.  Again, test is scoring higher).

I've looked around on the web and haven't found any helpful insights yet.  I've seen others says it may be due to the dataset being small, but this dataset has over 18,000 observations (13,090 for train and 5,611 for test).  Since the training and test scores are nearly identical, is this an issue?  What could be causing the test score to be higher?

The data for this ML project can be found [here](https://open.canada.ca/data/en/dataset/98f1a129-f628-4ce4-b24d-6f16bf24dd64).  I'm using 2000-2018 fuel consumption.

Comment: Have you tried different splits? Different ratios?

Comment: A similar question has been asked and answered here: [Test accuracy higher than training. How to interpret?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/59630/test-accuracy-higher-than-training-how-to-interpret)

Comment: +1 for splits

And also check correlation matrices across those splits. You have an important parameter (or parameters) here. So, if the correlation between it (or them) and target feature is not changing significantly (across different splits) - it is ok. You just have 'good' features in your model.

BTW, test score is not higher, it is the nearly same to the train score. May happen.

Comment: I tried numerous different splits and essentially go the same thing.  I went ahead and plotted the correlations of the different splits with the target variable and the correlations were pretty much the same.